# Python random number generator between 1 and 9

Tags: python, random

I created this code and it works fine, but I think it's ugly. Could you show me a better way to create a list of three different random numbers from 1 to 9?

```
class Baseball_Engine(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.random_number_list = [0, 0, 0]
        while self.count < 3:
            random_number = random.randint(1, 9)
            self.random_number_list[self.count] = random_number
                if self.random_number_list[self.count - 1] != random_number and self.random_number_list[self.count - 2] != random_number:
                self.count += 1
        print self.random_number_list
```

Comment: Please check your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Without dwelling too deep into your code there are a few alternatives. After a very quick google search, I stumbled upon this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655089/python-random-numbers-into-a-list).

They propose two different solutions.

```
import random
print random.sample(xrange(1, 10), 3)
```

This will create three distinct numbers with values ranging from 1 to 9. If you do not want the three numbers to be different, you could try the following

```
import random
print [random.randrange(1,10) for _ in range(3)]
```